# sum's sum of divizors of numbers less than or equal to N

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

I really need some help at this problem:

> Given a positive integer `N`, we define `xsum(N)` as sum's sum of all positive integer divisors' numbers less or equal to `N`.
>
> For example: xsum(6) = 1 + (1 + 2) + (1 + 3) + (1 + 2 + 4) + (1 + 5) + (1 + 2 + 3 + 6) = 33.
>   (xsum - sum of divizors of 1 + sum of divizors of 2 + ... + sum of div of 6)
>
> Given a positive integer `K`, you are asked to find the lowest `N` that satisfies the condition: `xsum(N) >= K`
>
> K is a nonzero natural number that has at most 14 digits
>
> time limit : 0.2 sec

Obviously, the brute force will fall for most cases with Time Limit Exceeded. I haven't find something better than it yet, so that's the code:

```
fscanf(fi,"%lld",&k);
i=2;
sum=1;
while(sum<k) {
    sum=sum+i+1;
    d=2;
    while(d*d<=i) {
          if(i%d==0 && d*d!=i)
             sum=sum+d+i/d;
          else
             if(d*d==i)
                 sum+=d;
           d++;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Any better ideas?

Comment: 14 digits means 14 bits? Or decimal digits? Anyway. This question is off-topic. SO is not code-rview site. If your code works, try on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). But first read their FAQ (you did not read that of SO apparently)!

Comment: 14 decimal digits. My code works and I put it because I read on the rules that you have to show your work, what you try to do etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each number `n` in range [1 , N] the following applies: `n` is divisor of exactly `roundDown(N / n)` numbers in range [1 , N]. Thus for each `n` we add a total of `n * roundDown(N / n)` to the result.

```
int xsum(int N){
    int result = 0;

    for(int i = 1 ; i <= N ; i++)
        result += (N / i) * i;//due to the int-division the two i don't cancel out

    return result;
}
```

The idea behind this algorithm can aswell be used to solve the main-problem (`smallest N such that xsum(N) >= K`) in faster time than brute-force search.

The complete search can be further optimized using some rules we can derive from the above code: `K = minN * minN` (`minN` would be the correct result if `K = 2 * 3 * ...)`. Using this information we have a lower-bound for starting the search.

Next step would be to search for the upper bound. Since the growth of `xsum(N)` is (approximately) quadratic we can use this to approximate `N`. This optimized guessing allows to find the searched value pretty fast.

```
int N(int K){
    //start with the minimum-bound of N
    int upperN = (int) sqrt(K);
    int lowerN = upperN;

    int tmpSum;
    //search until xsum(upperN) reaches K
    while((tmpSum = xsum(upperN)) < K){
        int r = K - tmpSum;

        lowerN = upperN;
        upperN += (int) sqrt(r / 3) + 1;
    }

    //Now the we have an upper and a lower bound for searching N
    //the rest of the search can be done using binary-search (i won't
    //implement it here)

    int N;//search for the value

    return N;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I have to admit that I didn't heard about Sieve of Atkin. I have to document before trying to understand this solution.

Comment: @scummy if performance isn't that important, you can simply use the Sieve of Erathostenes aswell

Comment: this is what I'm going to do

Comment: wait a sec, i've just thought through the whole thing and there's actually an a lot simpler solution to this problem. i'll edit

Comment: @scummy i've updated the answer with a simpler (linear) solution

Comment: I'm not sure that this will feat in time for all cases, but it's definetly better than the code I've wrote. Thanks!

Comment: @scummy i'll explain how to further optimize it

Comment: @scummy i've updated the answer with an algorithm that speeds search up with a pretty fast approximation and binary-search

Comment: @Paul, I'm unfamiliar with the result "For each number n in range [1 , N] the following applies: n is divisor of exactly roundDown(N / n) numbers in range [1 , N]", you have a quick reference for it?

Comment: @thurizas no need for a reference. That's just another way to express the number of numbers in range [1 , N] that are divisible by `n`. Let's say `N = 11` and `n = 3`. There are exactly `roundDown(11 / 3) = 3` numbers that are divisible by 3 in the range: `{3 , 6 , 9}`